What types of memory are impaired or enhanced in individuals with ADHD?
I'm looking for information on how memory is affected in individuals with ADHD. Specifically:

Do people with ADHD have impaired episodic memory?
Are there any types of memory that are enhanced in ADHD?
How does long-term memory in ADHD differ from that of neurotypical individuals?

I've found papers discussing long-term memory in ADHD, but not much on specific memory types, especially episodic memory. Could anyone point me to journal articles or research on this topic?
